# What is the function of the pronoun « y » in the expression « Il n’y manque pas une virgule, pas un iota. »?

Tags: pronoms, constructions

What is the function of the pronoun **y** in the expression *« Il n’**y** manque pas une virgule, pas un iota. »*?

Another way to ask this question is *“if the pronoun **y** was not present, what would be present instead?”* Another way to ask this question is *“What is the pronoun **y** replacing?”*

[image]

[Please click here to take you to ***Académie Française*** where this screenshot has been taken from.](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9M0575)

Thank you for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

*Y* is replacing the thing/place where something isn't missing/lacking...

If you want to replace the pronoun by its *antécédent*, you can say something like:

> Il ne manque pas une virgule à vos écrits.

> Il ne manque rien dans cet hôtel.

This pronoun is not mandatory in these sentences so you can also say:

> Il ne manque pas une virgule/un iota.

> Il ne manque rien.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again @jlliagre ! 